# Apply a rule vs. Follow a rule

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-requests, expression-choice

> - Don't insert a space before a colon.
> - Don't insert multiple consecutive colons.
> - **Follow the same rules for** commas, periods, and other punctuation marks.

> - Don't insert a space before a colon.
> - Don't insert multiple consecutive colons.
> - **Apply the same rules to** commas, periods, and other punctuation marks.

Is there a difference between "follow the same rule for" and "apply the same rule to"?

Which one is more idiomatic in such a context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Apply" is a more pragmatic term than "follow".
Both terms are equally idiomatic; the difference is in the level of appreciation of the action performed that is granted to the agent of that action; "apply" implies no concern with the opinion of the agent whereas "follow" implies a more educated choice being asked from the agent.

Comment: Engineering is the application of knowledge, which means knowledge (of science) is applied. Here, 'applied' cannot be replaced with 'followed'.

Comment: @RamPillai In the general case you choose this is true. You can say however in an engineering/a scientific context "follow the theory of" or "apply the theory of": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=follow+the+theory+of%2Capply+the++theory+of&year_end=2008&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&corpus=15&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfollow%20the%20theory%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capply%20the%20theory%20of%3B%2Cc0